# Unital nonalternative real division algebras of dimension 8

Tags: division-algebras, octonions

Cross-posted from [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2910224/unital-nonalternative-real-division-algebras-of-dimension-8) because I felt like it might be too obscure for there. I'm sorry if this is the wrong place for it.

EDIT: This question now has an answer over there

---

The finite-dimension division algebras over the reals are:

- $\Bbb R$: the reals (dimension 1)
- $\Bbb C$: the complex numbers (dimension 2)
- $\Bbb H$: the quaternions (dimension 4)
- $\Bbb O$: the octonions (dimension 8)
- *some other dimension 2 and dimension 8 things*

An example of a dimension-2 division algebra other that $\Bbb C$ is $(\Bbb C,*)$ with $a*b:=\overline{ab}$ (that is, the complex conjugate of the usual multiplication). This gives you $1*1=1$, $1*i=i*1=-i$, and $i*i=-1$. You'll notice that $1*a$ does not necessarily equal $a$; that is, this algebra is not *unital*. There exist nonunital division algebras of dimension 8 as well.

**Are there any *unital* division algebras of dimension 8 (other than $\Bbb O$)? Such an algebra cannot be alternative, nor can it have a norm (as each of these, together with the dimension 8 condition, uniquely define the octonions).**

(EDIT: The nonunital algebra defined above has a norm, but the only *unital* normed algebras are $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb C$, $\Bbb H$, and $\Bbb O$.)

Strangely, I haven't been able to find a source one way or another online, which is weird because it seems like it would close up the search for real division algebras. So, does such a thing exist?

Comment: This does not answer your question, but evidently there are examples over finite fields. https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927872.2017.1288235?journalCode=lagb20

Comment: It occurs to me that I should have written _some other dimension 2, dimension 4, and dimension 8 things_ in that last bullet point since $a*b=\overline{ab}$ generalizes to the quaternions as well.

Comment: What about dimension 4? Is it known?

Comment: @abx You know, I assumed nonassociative implies dimension 8, but I guess that might not actually be true. (Associative implies $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb C$, or $\Bbb H$, with or without the unital condition, at least according to Wikipedia.) If someone presented a unital dimension 4 division algebra other than $\Bbb H$ I'd accept it as an answer also.

Comment: Also, Wikipedia doesn't seem to be consistent between _unital_ and _unitary_.

Comment: I wonder if analyzing linearly independent vector fields on spheres will help us find, or prove the nonexistence of, such an algebra? (I know you can go the other way, that is, use algebras to find linearly independent vector fields on spheres.)

Comment: [This looks like it answers it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2910224/unital-nonalternative-real-division-algebras-of-dimension-8#comment6012467_2910224)

Comment: Why would it close up the search?  "Unital" is not a natural property for non-alternative algebras.

Comment: @arsmath I don't have much experience with nonalternative algebras, but 1\*a=a seemed pretty reasonable to me

Comment: In general, a division algebra satisfies that the equations $xz = y$ and $z'x = y$ always has a solution for any nonzero $x$.  For alternative algebras this implies the existence of a unit, but in general it doesn't.